# `find_value': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) while parsing response

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm calling a SOAP method using savon 2.11.2 and ruby 2.4.1p111

I get that error:

```
C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nori-2.6.0/lib/nori.rb:72:in `find_value': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nori-2.6.0/lib/nori.rb:38:in `find'
    from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/savon-2.11.2/lib/savon/soap_fault.rb:36:in `message_by_version'
    from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/savon-2.11.2/lib/savon/soap_fault.rb:25:in `to_s'
    from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sensu-plugin-2.3.0/lib/sensu-plugin/cli.rb:65:in `message'
    from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sensu-plugin-2.3.0/lib/sensu-plugin/cli.rb:65:in `rescue in block in <class:CLI>'
    from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sensu-plugin-2.3.0/lib/sensu-plugin/cli.rb:55:in `block in <class:CLI>'
```

when calling:

```
client.call(:get_integration_events_request, message: request(system, actual_page))
```

I don't get that error every time only for a specific response, only thing i can see different on that response is it has CDATA and new lines inside one of the fields

I called same SOAP using SOAPUI and parse the output using nori

```
parser = Nori.new
parser.parse(
```

and it parse without any issue, but SAVON is clearly failing to parse the response before I can do anything

I tried to change default parser from nokogiri to rexml with same result

Comment: Can you give us some more info, maybe a working and the broken response?

Comment: Response is quite big and I will have to clean the data first so probably not really useful to share it.
I get a list of events, if i say give me the last 3 it works, when i say give me the last 4 it fails so it must be that 4th event, i have copied the response, using soap ui and debug mode at savon) and repsonse can be parsed if i use nori directly so SAVON must be doing something else

Only differences I can see between 'good' and 'bad' event is that the one that fails include CDATA and fields containing new lines

Comment: I manage to narrow the problem

I'm calling a SOAP method using savon 2.11.2 and ruby 2.4.1p111
Response include
```
<Message_Summary><![CDATA[Integration Failed.
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client.Authentication</faultcode>
<faultstring>The Gateway has rejected the Credentials.</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
]]>
</Message_Summary>
```

Savon believes it is a SOAPFault and raise an exception but in fact response was OK

Also in my particular case as it believes is a SOAP error length is limited to 6510 and raise "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" when printing the error